# ERROR [SequelizeModule] Unable to connect to the database

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs

I keep facing this error when starting up my Nest Application:

**`[Nest] 53044  - 08/10/2023, 1:51:34 AM   ERROR [SequelizeModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...`**

**Here's my app.module:**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UsersModule } from './modules/users/users.module';
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { Dialect } from 'sequelize';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as Joi from 'joi';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      validationSchema: Joi.object({
        DATABASE_HOST: Joi.string().required(),
        DATABASE_PORT: Joi.number().required(),
        DATABASE_NAME: Joi.string().required(),
        DATABASE_USER: Joi.string().required(),
        DATABASE_PASS: Joi.string(),
        DATABASE_DIALECT: Joi.string().required(),
        APPS_PORT: Joi.number().required(),
        // SALT_ROUND: Joi.number().required(),
      }),
    }),
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      dialect: 'postgres' as Dialect,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'databaseName',
      autoLoadModels: true,
      synchronize: true,
      logging: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

**Here's my Users modules and their model, respectively:**

Users.module:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
  imports: [SequelizeModule.forFeature([User])],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Users.entity:

```
import { Column, DataType, Model, Table } from 'sequelize-typescript';
@Table({
  timestamps: true,
})
export class User extends Model<User> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  username: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  password: string;
}
```

---

I am using Sequelize and Postgres, and the database is already created.
My db connection configuration is correct (dbName, user, pass, host, port).

What is causing the problem really? I have another app with exact configuration and it works just fine.

The error occurred when I set `autoLoadModels: true`.
It is gone when I set it to false but I've got another error when I actually trying to query to  database:
`ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Model not initialized: Member "findAll" cannot be called. "User" needs to be added to a Sequelize instance.`

So, setting it to false doesn't really solve the issue, since my app is not connected to database at all.

I tried using the same package version as my other working app.
I tried using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.
I tried deleting my node_modules and reinstall my packages.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here. I set autoLoadModels to false and it worked for me

So it turned out you can't have both:
imports: [SequelizeModule.forFeature([User])],
and
autoLoadModels : true

at the same time. At least in my case it was like that.

Comment: `autoLoadModels : false` helped in my case too